# Error when calling findElement after findElements on webdriver.WebElement (using Protractor, JS)

Tags: selenium, promise, protractor

I'm using Protractor (Angular JS's webdriver wrapper), and although I can chain `findElement` indefinitely off of a single `WebElement` instance, I get an error when I attempt to chain `findElement` after using `findElements` (plural).

**Error** *(stack trace given at bottom)*:

> TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'findElement'

**Chaining findElement**:

```js
var elementPromise = browser.findElement(by.css('body')).findElement(by.css('ul')).findElement(by.css('li'));
elementPromise.findElement(by.css('.icon-meter')); // does not raise error
```

**Using findElement after findElements**:

```js
var arrayPromise = browser.findElement(by.css('ul')).findElements(by.css('li'));
elementPromise = arrayPromise.then(function(elems) {
    return elems[0];
});
elementPromise.findElement(by.css('.icon-meter')); // => raises error
```

**Error message with trace**

```
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'findElement'
at repl:1:16
at /home/markham/src/dataraptor-rails4/spec/node_modules/elementexplorer-convenience.js:83:19
at webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runInNewFrame_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1598:20)
at webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runEventLoop_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1463:8)
at wrapper [as _onTimeout] (timers.js:252:14)
at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I got the same problem with the version 0.24 of protractor.

As a workaround, i have replaced all the invocation of `findElement()` by `element()` and all `findElements()` by `all()`.

**Chaining element**:

```js
var elementPromise = browser.element(by.css('body')).element(by.css('ul')).element(by.css('li'));
elementPromise.element(by.css('.icon-meter'));
```

**Using findElement after findElements**:

```js
var arrayPromise = browser.element(by.css('ul')).all(by.css('li'));
elementPromise = arrayPromise.then(function(elems) {
    return elems[0];
});
elementPromise.element(by.css('.icon-meter'));
```

There is more details on this release in this [g+ post](https://plus.google.com/114845304720350465605/posts/3qu7E46Lwuw)

Comment: Alas, too often the answer is 'upgrade'. Looks like this introduces some non-backward compatible changes. Going to have to refactor quite a bit.